# Brocade FCX648-I In password recovery process

Tags: networking, switch, brocade

Brocade FCX648-I In password recovery process I get to a Monitor> prompt. The password recovery instructions tell me to assign a new password at this point but doesn't tell me how. There is a link to click on "Assigning new passwords" but when I go there the instructions don't make much sense and when I try to follow them all that happens is that I get right back to the switch login asking me for a password ???????

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like their storage stuff (and I know it's usually not), it's loosely based on unix. Try typing `passwd` and see if it lets you reset your password.